# UICollectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath not called when tapped on UITextView

Tags: ios, ios7, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` with custom cells- They have a `UITextView` that mostly covers the entire cell. This presents a problem when using `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`. The only way to trigger it is by tapping outside the `UITextView`. I want it to trigger wherever in the cell you tap, whether there is a text view or not. How can this be done?

Comment: I would suggest to use `UIGestureRecognizer` for each cell and when it taped to send it to text view or whatever , perhaps there maybe a better solutions , but i would use this 1

Comment: Problem solved by adding a UITapGestureRecognizer (thanks @Roma-MT) and using indexPathForItemAtPoint:

Comment: Then I will make an answer :).

Comment: Can you please share your code? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use `UIGestureRecognizer` for each cell and when it taped to send it to `UITextView` or whatever , perhaps there maybe a better solutions , but I would use this 1 because of simplicity reasons.

Answer (score 29):

`didSelectItemAtIndexPath` is called when `none of the subView of collectionViewCell respond to that touch`. As the `textView` respond to those touches, so it `won't forward those touches` to its superView, so collectionView won't get it.

override `hitTest:withEvent` method of your `collectionViewCell` or `CollectionView` subclass and always return `self` from them.so it explicitly makes collectionView as `first responder`.

Comment: I added this code to my UICollectionViewCell implementation: `- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    return self;
}
` This completely disabled the clicking, now it doesn't even trigger when tapped outside the text view.

Comment: are you sure you didn't implement touchesBegan method in UICollectionViewCell.You should not override touchesBegan in cell.

Comment: While the problem is solved, I can tell you that there are no touches-methods. Here is the code if you're interested `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setTextViewText:(NSString *)text {
    self.textView.text = text;
}
- (void)setTitleLabelText:(NSString *)text {
    self.titleLabel.text = text;
}`

Comment: This was the reason for the issue I had. By disabling user interaction on my text views the touch events began being forwarding to my delegate.

Comment: Hey @santhu, is there any way we could do this without removing the user interaction in the text view?

Comment: @AbdullahAjmal I am not sure what you want exactly. To my understanding, if you want to recognise them simultaneously, you have apis like recognise gesture simultaneously delegate methods. You can play with that. But i will say it is bad way to make a touch be responded by both textView and collectionView according to iOS standards.

Answer (score 2):

Do you override `touchesEnded: withEvent:` ?

I had the same problem today and I found that I have some customised logic in `touchesEnded` in one of collectionview's container views, and I didn't call

```
 [super touchesEnded: withEvent:]
```

when I'm done with my customised logic in `touchesEnded`.

After adding the super call, everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Select `UITextView`, in that specific case `UICollectionViewCell`, and switch to attribute inspector. The uncheck **User interaction enabled** and it should work fine.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just do this

```
textview.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when I had a scroll view taking up my entire collection view cell.  While all the solutions above probably work fine, I came up with my own elegant work-around.  I put a 'select' label under my scroll view.  Since the label is not part of the scroll view, it passes the tap event on to the collection view.  It also serves as a nice indicator that an action is required of the user.