# didSelectItemAtIndexPath Doesn't Work In Collection View Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have been working on a new application and it displays Gifs in a Collection View. I am also using a custom collection view cell class for the cells in my collection view.

The method `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` doesn't work though ...

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    println("it worked")

    // ^this did not print
}
```

How would I change it so I can get the indexPath of the clicked item using a gesture recognizer?

Comment: Try this: [UICollectionView only calling didSelectItemAtIndexPath if user double taps, will not call when user single taps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41137784/4935811)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

as @santhu said (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21970378/846780)

> didSelectItemAtIndexPath is called when none of the subView of
>   collectionViewCell respond to that touch. As the textView respond to
>   those touches, so it won't forward those touches to its superView, so
>   collectionView won't get it.

So, you have a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` and it avoid `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` call.

With `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` approach you need to handle `handleLongPress` delegate method. Basically you need to get `gestureReconizer.locationInView` and know the indexPath located at this point (`gestureReconizer.locationInView`).

```
    func handleLongPress(gestureReconizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if gestureReconizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
            return
        }

        let p = gestureReconizer.locationInView(self.collectionView)
        let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(p)

        if let index = indexPath {
            var cell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(index)
            // do stuff with your cell, for example print the indexPath
             println(index.row)
        } else {
            println("Could not find index path")
        }
    }
```