# How to pass collectionview cells index value to nextviewcontroller(using push navigation) in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, pushviewcontroller

I am using collectionview in tableview cell,

**i need to pass selected collectionview cells value to next viewcontroller**, how?

code: here is the code for tableview and collectionview cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoryNewTableCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryNewTableCell

        let indexData = self.activeCategories?[indexPath.row]
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.catNameLbl.text = indexData?.details?.first?.title

        cell.subCategories = indexData?.sub_categories
        cell.clcSeller.reloadData()
 }



class CategoryNewTableCell: UITableViewCell,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource{

@IBOutlet weak var clcSeller: UICollectionView!

public var subCategories : Array<Sub_categories>?

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return subCategories?.count ?? 0
 }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SubCatCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! SubCatCollectionCell

    let subCategory = self.subCategories?[indexPath.item]
    cell.lblTitle.text = langType == .en ? subCategory?.details?.first?.title : subCategory?.details?[1].title

    return cell
 }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let vc = StoryBoard.main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchResultVC") as! SearchResultVC
    vc.subCatId = sub_categories?[indexPath.row].slug ?? ""
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}

}
```

here if i use `didSelectItemAt` for collectionview to send its selected cell value to next view controller

error:

> Value of type 'CategoryNewTableCell' has no member 'navigationController'

**if i give button action in main class then able to push but value is not going**

```
class CategoryNewVC: UIViewController {

@IBAction func didselectcollectionviewBTn(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let vc = StoryBoard.main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchResultVC") as! SearchResultVC

    vc.subCatId = //here how to pass value

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
 }
}
```

**here how to pass selected collectionview cells value to `SearchResultVC` please do help**

**EDIT**

according to below answer i have added: still `didSelectItemAt` not called, why plz do help

```
  class CategoryNewTableCell: UITableViewCell,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource{

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    
    self.clcSeller.delegate = self
    self.clcSeller.dataSource = self
```

//

Comment: Create an integer variable at the receiver side.  And pass a number to it before you push the receiver view controller.

Comment: @ElTomato yes it is there in reciverVc `subCatId ` but how to send `subCategory?.details?.first?.title` value to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Declare a callback in the tableViewCell subclass.

```
class CategoryNewTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    var onSelectSubcategory: ((_ subcategoryID: String) -> Void)?
}
```

2. Assign this callback in your `cellForRow` like this.

```
cell.subCategories = indexData?.sub_categories
cell.onSelectSubcategory = { [weak self] (subcategoryID) in
    let vc = StoryBoard.main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchResultVC") as! SearchResultVC
    vc.subCatId = subcategoryID
    self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

3. Invoke this callback from collectionView `didSelectItem` like this.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let subcategoryID = sub_categories?[indexPath.item].slug ?? ""
    self.onSelectSubcategory?(subcategoryID)
}
```

Comment: in this line `let subcategoryID = sub_categories?[indexPath.item].slug ?? ""` instead of `sub_categories` i have added `subCategories ` but nothing works.. no error.. and not going to next VC as well

Comment: `didSelectItemAt` is not calling... why?

Comment: You should add `clcSeller.delegate = self` in your tableViewCell subclass. Otherwise the delegate method won't be called.

Comment: i have added like this for `delegate` still `didSelectItemAt ` not calling plz do help

Comment: Can you share more code where you assign delegate `clcSeller.delegate = self` inside the tableViewCell subclass?

Comment: what is `tableViewCell ` i have added it in tableview `cellForRowAt` which is added in my post as well please gothroug my post below section.. i have edited

Comment: When you write `cell.clcSeller.delegate = self` inside the `cellForRow` call, this makes your `UIViewController` subclass the delegate. You are expecting the delegate callback in your `UITableViewCell` subclass i.e. `CategoryNewTableCell`. So you have to write that line in there. That's what I meant by **tableViewCell subclass** in the previous comment.

Comment: sorry, i have added it already.. how i added is edited in my question.. plz take a look.. still not calling `didSelectItemAt `

Comment: do u know why `didSelectItemAt ` is not calling?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234770/discussion-between-swift-and-tarun-tyagi).

Comment: if i add button to collectionview cell then in button action i am unable to pass `homeData?.result?.category_json?[indexPath.section].sub_categories?[indexPath.row].slug ?? ""`

Comment: `[indexPath.section]` is showing error..  `[indexPath.row]` i have added `[sendr.tag]`

Comment: plz do help in any one of it

Comment: Please try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681643/didselectitematindexpath-doesnt-work-in-collection-view-swift

Comment: i dont understand that :(

Answer (score 3):

You can use protocol to send data to your nextviewcontroller.

```
protocol CategorySelectionDelegate {
    func get(category: Sub_categories)
}
```

Declare the delegate in your CategoryNewTableCell and use it in didSelectItemAt method of your collectionviewcell like below:

```
class CategoryNewTableCell:
    UITableViewCell,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource{
    
    @IBOutlet weak var clcSeller: UICollectionView!
    
    public var subCategories : Array<Sub_categories>?
    
    var delegate: CategorySelectionDelegate?
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return subCategories?.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SubCatCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! SubCatCollectionCell
        
        let subCategory = self.subCategories?[indexPath.item]
        cell.lblTitle.text = langType == .en ? subCategory?.details?.first?.title : subCategory?.details?[1].title
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        delegate?.get(category: sub_categories?[indexPath.row])
    }
}
```

Adopt the protocol in the receiving class

```
class CategoryNewVC: UIViewController, CategorySelectionDelegate {
    func get(category: Sub_categories) {
        let vc = StoryBoard.main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchResultVC") as! SearchResultVC
        vc.subCatId = category.slug ?? ""
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```